# Rotate image uploaded via email using PIL for Django website

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

My website allows users to upload photos to their gallery via email and it works perfectly.  However, photos taken on the iPhone in portrait mode do NOT rotate correctly.  I would like to rotate the photo using PIL during the "mail filtering" process.  Here is the code that I am using to successfully retrieve the image from the email and save to my Django model

```
    image = ContentFile(b64decode(part.get_payload()))
    img = Photo(user=user)
    filename = part.get_filename().lower()
    img.img.save(filename, image)
    img.save()
```

***Updated code that successfully rotates temp image to local dir** *

```
     image = ContentFile(b64decode(part.get_payload()))
     im = Image.open(image)
     tempfile = im.rotate(90)
     tempfile.save("/srv/www/mysite.com/public_html/media/images/rotate.jpg", "JPEG")
     img = Photo(user=user)
     img.img.save('rotate.jpg', tempfile)
     img.save()
```

Now, I'm trying to take the "temp image" and save it to my model. Unfortunately, it is not saving. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

clearly states that rotate() returns an new image instance.

There is nothing in the documentation about in-place operations. Or?

Comment: So, if I am creating a new image instance, why can't I just save the new instance?

Comment: Ok, I created a variable "im", opened the image object, rotated it, and then saved it. Assigned the "im" variable to my save method.  Unfortunately, still doesn't work.  Thanks for the fishing pole and not just giving me fish :) Still need help.

Comment: I was able to successfully rotate image by saving the rotated image to local dir.  Now I'm trying to save to my model, but am unsuccessful.  Any suggestions?